# One Incorrect value from single data point using sqlcmd query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

SQL query using sqlcmd is missing/showing default date for one datapoint using a Join - Problem

I am using sqlcmd to query a large database. For one datapoint (SalesTransaction #33975) the date is coming up as blank or rather 1/1/1900. Using a separate program the date comes through so the date is there. The other dates are correct

```
SELECT sl.SalesLine, st.Transaction_no, sl.item, CAST(st.invoicedate as DATE) AS InvDate
FROM Salestransactions st RIGHT JOIN SalesLines sl 
ON st.transaction_no = sl.transaction_no;
```

For `Transaction_No = 3397` the `Invoice Date = 1/1/1900`
I have not filtered for this transaction rather the dates for the other transactions are correct. I have tried to keep the coding simple to help pinpoint the problem. I simply need some direction on how to research this further. Thank you

Comment: Data usually doesn't disappear from a table unless someone deletes or updates it, and then same query against the same table should always produce the same result, no matter where executed.  Help to make your question reproducible by telling us how to reproduce your problem.

Comment: There's no way to definitely answer your question on the little information you've posted. Post the table definitions and the output of `select * from salestransactions where transaction_no = 33975` and  `select * from saleslines where transaction_no = 33975`

Comment: You might have different transaction isolation configurations with each client, one is reading dirty and another commited. Or the one client is displaying a null date as empty or as a default value of 1900-01-01.

Comment: The code above is the code I used, very simple to pinpoint the problem. When I use sqlcmd to run this query, the default invoice date appears for one specific transaction number, 3397. I have not filtered for this number, but have checked this number from a different source. Using PowerBI sql query, I do get an invoice date. Thank you EzLo for your suggestion of dirty or commited configurations, I will read up on these. I did also run a basic query without a join and the default date again appears. Dates for all other transactions are correct. It appears this is a question for Microsoft.